# put a link in pop up window

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, popup

I am trying to make a link out of a pop up button.

```
 <button onclick="myFunction4()">Resist Elements</button>
 <script>
        function myFunction4() { 
            var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, 
                resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");

            myWindow.document.write("<b>Resist Elements:</b> At 2nd level, druids gain a +2 bonus to saving throws against fire, water, earth, air, cold and lightning attacks. ");
        }
</script>
```

For instance, I want the word "attacks" to link to something, such as http://www.google.com.  Each time I put in an a href that particular button won't open.

Comment: What does the JavaScript console say? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: ... `<a href='http://www.google.com'>attacks</a>` ... (with ' instead of ") not working?

Comment: I don't see a link in your code. Please show the non-working code so we can tell what you did wrong.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you, I totally missed that!